# Creating a new viewset with multiple filters for the viewset get method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi i have a viewset that I am creating. I want to over ride the the get functino and get all the records that have the filtered parameter which is passed into the get view. I also want to be able to do the rest of the crud functionality - GET POST PUT DELETE - and use the paramater that is passed through the url as a parameter for the POST and UPDATE.

Right now, when i pass in the parameter, rather than filter the data that is returned, it is giving me no details found which is not what i want. i want it to be used as a secondary filter for all the records that i get back from the database.

Here is the code:

viewset

```
class PreferenceUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1)
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer

class PreferenceNamespaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1)
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else: 
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
    def list(self, request, namespace=None):
        # switch user_id value with logged in users id
        queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1, namespace=namespace)
        serializer = PreferenceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls:

```
    path('preferences/<str:namespace>/', PreferenceNamespaceViewSet.as_view({
        'get':'list'
    })),
    path('users/<int:pk>/stacks/', person_stack, name='user-stacks'),
```

I want to use the `namepsace` as a secondary filter to all the data that is returned in the GET. I also want to use it as a peice of data that I can enter when creating a new preference.

** I also want to do the samething with a third potential parameter like so... **

potential third parameters:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('preferences/<str:namespace>/<str:path>', PreferencePathViewSet.as_view({
        'get':'list'
    })),
    path('preferences/<str:namespace>/', PreferenceNamespaceViewSet.as_view({
        'get':'list'
    })),
    path('users/<int:pk>/stacks/', person_stack, name='user-stacks'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't add namespace as url parameter, instead you can use [**`URL querystring`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to fetch namespace information(as well as other parameters). for example:

```
# URL
path('preferences/', PreferencePathViewSet.as_view({
        'get':'list'
    })
),

# view
class PreferenceNamespaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1)
    serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        else: 
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Preference.objects.all()
        namespace = request.GET.get('namespace', None)
        if namespace:
             queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=1, namespace=namespace)
        serializer = PreferenceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```